# index not recognized as chapter

Tags: indexing

I'm using a text using `book` class. Everything is fine, apart from the fact that the index isn't recognized as a chapter. Using

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

I'm still able to produce an entry "Index" in the `ToC`, but the heading in the index are the same as in the previous section of the book. In other words, LaTeX doesn't seem to recognize the index as such. Is there anything I can do, beside modifying the headings manually?

Comment: How do you print your index? Try using `\cleardoublepage\markboth{Index}{Index}` immediately before your index printing.

Comment: There's the `\tocetmark` command for this, as far as I know.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Strange enough, yours is an "undefined control sequence".

Comment: @Delio: Sorry, a typo: I meant `\tocetcmark`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Ok, I tried with \tocetcmark{Index}, but for some strange reason the Index "expands" and I find the corresponding heading in *some* pages of the preceding sections as well. A bit spooky... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Delio: Well, without seeing any code we can't provide further help

Comment: @Delio: I converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
\cleardoublepage
\markboth{Index}{Index}
```

immediately before your setting of the Index *should* update the headers `Index` rather than that of what preceded the Index chapter/section.